# passing page arguments to drupal 8 from controller to form controller

Tags: 8

This is my code in routing.yml file

```
test.check-test:
  path: 'node/{node}/test'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\test\Form\Test'
    _title: 'Test'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access test'
```

I need to get the value of node in the form controller buildForm function.

How can I access that? Any help?

Comment: $node = \Drupal::request()->get('node'); I think, it would work for your situation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the `.routing.yml` file like so:

```
test.check-test:
  path: 'node/{node}/test'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\test\Form\Test'
    _title: 'Test'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access test'
    node: \d+
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
```

Then use it in your form controller the following way:

```
namespace Drupal\test\Form;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

class Test extends FormBase {
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, NodeInterface $node = NULL) {
    $form['placeholder'] = [
      '#markup' => t('This is the form for @node_title.', [
        '@node_title' => $node->getTitle(),
      ]),
    ];

    return $form;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry.This resulted an error 'Object of class Drupal\node\Entity\Node could not be converted to string'

Comment: Did you clear the cache after updating the routing.yml file?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark it as a solution so others with the same problem know that this answered the question. Comments can get deleted after some time.

Answer (score 0):

There are one way with two approaches:

Either calling the request service statically:

- `$request_param= \Drupal::request()->query->get('myparam');`

Or call it via Dependency injection:

```
return new static(
  $container->get('request_stack')
);
```

And then just add to the end of the constructor's argument list: `RequestStack $request_stack`

And save it as own property, which you can use later: `$this->requestStack = $request_stack;`